# Need help passing values to post form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the values in a form based on which radio button is selected. It's passing the key to the php but not the value to my php. I'm trying to send it via POST and picking up the variables on the other side

I'm working off the example found here : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sexy-radio-butons

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
input[type=submit] {
    width: 5em;  height: 2em;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#radioBtn .notActive{
    color: #3276b1;
    background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<h2>Notification settings for: ****@vtext.com</h2>
<br>
<br>
<form action="http://****.com/temp_update_notifications.php?v=1530296464" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" value="YgSeBiAcEg">
  <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="****@vtext.com">
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Update">
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
          <div class="input-group">

              <b>Current setting: Active</b>
              <br>
              <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="-1">No Change</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="0">Active</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="1">1 Hour</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="3">3 Hours</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="8">8 Hours</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="12">12 Hours</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="24">24 Hours</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="3885 Walkin Door" data-title="168">7 days</a>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="3885 Walkin Door" id="3885 Walkin Door">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
<script>
$('#radioBtn a').on('click', function(){
    var sel = $(this).data('title');
   var tog = $(this).data('toggle');
  $('#'+tog).prop('value', sel);

    $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"]').not('[data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
    $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"][data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('notActive').addClass('active');
})
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a same 'name' and 'value' identifier on each button tag.

Then just call the the name.

Example:

```
HTML:

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" name="WalkinDoor" value="-1">No Change</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" name="WalkinDoor" value="0">Active</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" name="WalkinDoor" value="1">1 Hour</a>


PHP:

$buttonValue = $_POST['WalkinDoor'];
```

Comment: I need to be able to change the values using the javascript in my code.